# Find index of xml attributes using mule dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, dataweave

I have requirement as print index of xml attribute

```
<Item>
    <HeaderCharges>
      <HeaderCharge ChargeCategory="ShippingCharge" ChargeName="ShippingCharge1" ChargeAmount="10.0" Reference="Free delivery">
        <Extn BaseChargeAmount="10.0" DeliveryCode="" DeliverySequenceNo="1" ConsignmentNo="0000164182"  ItemID="1452778282"/>
    </HeaderCharge>   
    <HeaderCharge ChargeCategory="ShippingDiscount" ChargeName="ShippingDiscount1" ChargeAmount="6.0" Reference="Discount">
        <Extn BaseChargeAmount="6.0" DeliveryCode="" DeliverySequenceNo="1" ConsignmentNo="0000164182"  ItemID="1452778282"
        POSDepartmentID="1097" PromotionID="100819" Description="" ReasonClass="PROMOVCH" ReasonCode="1230" ReasonDescription="50%off" />
    </HeaderCharge>
    <HeaderCharge ChargeCategory="ShippingDiscount" ChargeName="ShippingDiscount2" ChargeAmount="4.0" Reference="Discount 2">
        <Extn BaseChargeAmount="4.0" DeliveryCode="" DeliverySequenceNo="1" ConsignmentNo="0000164182"  ItemID="1452778282"
        POSDepartmentID="1097" PromotionID="100819" ReasonClass="PROMOVCH" ReasonCode="1230" ReasonDescription="50%off" />
    </HeaderCharge>
    <HeaderCharge ChargeCategory="ShippingCharge" ChargeName="ShippingCharge1" ChargeAmount="10.0" Reference="Free delivery">
        <Extn BaseChargeAmount="10.0" DeliveryCode="" DeliverySequenceNo="2" ConsignmentNo="0000164182"  ItemID="1452778282"/>
    </HeaderCharge> 
        </HeaderCharges>
</Item>
```

when `ChargeCategory="ShippingCharge"` then index should be 1, for the next iteration index should be 2. Need to find index for `ChargeCategory="ShippingCharge"`.

I tried with $$ but its supporting only for xml nodes, not for attributes

Code - `

```
%dw 1.0
 %input payload application/xml
 %output application/xml

 %var counter=sizeOf payload.Order.OrderLines.*OrderLine
 %var counter1=sizeOf payload.Order.HeaderCharges.*HeaderCharge

 %var head=sizeOf payload.Order.HeaderCharges.*HeaderCharge.@ChargeCategory == "ShippingCharge" distinctBy $.@ChargeCategory
 ---
using (w=payload.Order.OrderLines.*OrderLine default [], a=payload.Order.PaymentMethods.*PaymentMethod default [],h=payload.Order.HeaderCharges.*HeaderCharge default [], z=payload.Order.HeaderCharges.*HeaderCharge filter $.ChargeCategory == "ShippingCharge" default [])



Transaction @(CancelFlag:"false"):{((payload.*Order default []) map {

        RetailTransaction: {

((h default []) map ({ // HeaderCharge Level
   LineItem @(EntryMethod:"Keyed"):{

            SequenceNumber:counter + $$ + 1,     
            BeginDateTime:payload.Order.@OrderDate[0..18],
            EndDateTime:payload.Order.PosLogDataList.PosLogData.@EndDateTime[0..18],

            CustomerOrderForDelivery @(OrderStatus:"Sale"):{
                 Quantity:"1",
                 Associate:{
                        AssociateID:payload.Order.PosLogDataList.PosLogData.@AssociateID
                    },


                (($ default []) groupBy $.@DeliverySequenceNo map ({
                RetailPriceModifier @(MethodCode:"AutomaticPromotion",VoidFlag:"false"):{
                    SequenceNumber1: $$,
                    Amount @(Action:"Subtract"):$.Extn.@BaseChargePerUnit,
                    PreviousPrice:$.Extn.@BaseUnitPrice when $$ == 0 otherwise $.Extn.@BaseUnitPrice - [$$ - 1 ].Extn.@BaseChargePerUnit,
                    NewPrice:""

                }
                }) when $.@ChargeCategory == "ShippingCharge" otherwise {}) 
                }

            }

            }

            ) when $.HeaderCharges != '' otherwise {})

            }

            }

            )

            }
```

`  Here  SequenceNumber1 should come as 1,2 as per above mentioned HeaderChargers condition

Sample input -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order AuthorizationExpirationDate="2016-06-22T14:43:05+00:00"
    BillToID="8801533001732" CarrierAccountNo=" " CarrierServiceCode=" "
    ChargeActualFreightFlag="N" Createts="2016-06-22T14:43:05+00:00"
      TermsCode=" " TotalAdjustmentAmount="0.00" evaluate="yes" isHistory="N">
       <Extn BaseOrderTotal="385.00" BaseOriginalOrderTotal="385.00"
        CustomerID="63873" InstoreID="147258" IsFraudCancelled="N"
        IsMarketingPref="N" OrderTotal="385.00"
        OriginalTotalAmount="385.00" TerminalID="704292"/>
    <OrderLines>
        <OrderLine AllocationDate="2016-06-24T00:00:00+00:00"
            CarrierAccountNo=" " CarrierServiceCode="NDD_COU"
            CustomerLinePONo=" " CustomerPONo=" " DeliveryCode=" "
            DepartmentCode=" " FreightTerms=" " HoldFlag="N"
            HoldReasonCode=" " ImportLicenseNo=" " InvoicedQty="0.00"
            ScacAndServiceKey="" ShipNode="1097" ShipTogetherNo=" "
            SplitQty="0.00" Status="Created" StatusQuantity="30.00"
            SubLineNo="1" isHistory="N">
            <OrderStatuses>
                <OrderStatus OrderHeaderKey="2016062214430220261511"
                    OrderLineKey="2016062214430420261512"
                    OrderLineScheduleKey="201606221437430520261529"
                    OrderReleaseStatusKey="201606221477430520261530"
                    PipelineKey="20160222070748372596" Status="1100"
                    StatusDate="2016-06-22T14:43:04+00:00"
                    StatusDescription="Created" StatusQty="30.00" TotalQuantity="30.00"/>
            </OrderStatuses>
            <OrderDates>
                <OrderDate ActualDate="2016-06-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                    CommittedDate="2016-06-24T00:00:00+00:00"
                    DateTypeId="YCD_FIRST_PROMISED_DATE"
                    OrderHeaderKey="2016062214430220261511"
                    OrderLineKey="2016062214430420261512" OrderReleaseKey=" "/>
            </OrderDates>
            <Instructions NumberOfInstructions="0"/>
            <Item AliasName="" AliasValue="" CostCurrency=" "
                CountryOfOrigin=" " CustomerItem=" "
                CustomerItemDesc=" " ECCNNo=" "
                HarmonizedCode="6203423100" ISBN=" "
                ItemDesc="product &quot;101351803&quot; with name &quot;501 Stonewash Straight Jeans&quot;"
                ItemID="101351803"
                ItemShortDesc=" &quot;501 Stonewash Straight Jeans&quot;"
                ItemWeight="0.70" ItemWeightUOM="KG"
                ManufacturerItem=" " ManufacturerItemDesc=" "
                ManufacturerName="Levi's" NMFCClass=" " NMFCCode=" "
                NMFCDescription=" " ProductClass="Good" ProductLine=" "
                ScheduleBCode=" " SupplierItem=" " SupplierItemDesc=" "
                TaxProductCode="default" UPCCode=" " UnitCost="0.00" UnitOfMeasure="EACH"/>
            <ItemDetails CanUseAsServiceTool="N" GlobalItemID=""
                IsItemSuperseded="N" ItemGroupCode="PROD"
                ItemID="101351803" ItemKey="20160406111557582111"
                OrganizationCode="HOF" UnitOfMeasure="EACH">
                <ItemAliasList>
                    <ItemAlias AliasName="EAN" AliasValue="5412456008434"/>
                </ItemAliasList>
            </ItemDetails>
            <Extn AgeRestricted="N" BaseLineTotal="600.00"
                BaseListPrice="12.00" BaseUnitPrice="20.00"
                ConsignmentNo="0000217069-1" DeliverySequenceNo="1"
                HybrisLineNo="1" LineTotal="600.00" POSDepartmentID="0049"/>
            <LinePriceInfo DiscountPercentage="0.00" IsPriceLocked="N"
                LineTotal="360.00" ListPrice="12.00" RetailPrice="0.00"
                TaxableFlag="N" UnitPrice="20.00"/>
            <PersonInfoShipTo AddressID="8802157101079"
                AddressLine1="HighSroad1" AddressLine2="Nattf"
                AddressLine3="" AddressLine4="" AddressLine5=""
                AddressLine6="" AlternateEmailID="" Beeper=""
                City="Trava1234" Company="" Country="UK" DayFaxNo=""
                DayPhone="" Department="" EMailID="" EveningFaxNo=""
                EveningPhone="" FirstName="Ferand" JobTitle=""
                LastName="abcd" MiddleName="" MobilePhone="9876551111"
                OtherPhone="" PersonID=""
                PersonInfoKey="2016062214430520261527" State=""
                Suffix="" Title="Mr" ZipCode="2000"/>
            <LineCharges>
                <LineCharge ChargeAmount="240.00"
                    ChargeCategory="SystemPromotion"
                    ChargeName="12% on purchase over paypal"
                    ChargeNameKey="" ChargePerLine="0.00"
                    ChargePerUnit="8.00" InvoicedChargeAmount="0.00"
                    InvoicedChargePerLine="0.00"
                    InvoicedChargePerUnit="0.00" IsBillable="Y"
                    IsDiscount="Y"
                    Reference="percentage off on purchase over paypal"
                    RemainingChargeAmount="240.00"
                    RemainingChargePerLine="0.00" RemainingChargePerUnit="8.00">
                    <Extn BaseChargeAmount="240.00"
                        BaseChargePerLine="0.00"
                        BaseChargePerUnit="8.00"
                        PromotionID="0000100253"
                        ReasonClass="12%  on purchase over debit card"
                        ReasonCode="12% on purchase over debit card" ReasonDescription="percentage off on purchase over paypal"/>
                </LineCharge>
            </LineCharges>
        </OrderLine>
    </OrderLines>
   <HeaderCharges>
  <HeaderCharge ChargeCategory="ShippingCharge" ChargeName="ShippingCharge1" ChargeAmount="10.0" Reference="Free delivery">
    <Extn BaseChargeAmount="10.0" DeliveryCode="" DeliverySequenceNo="1" ConsignmentNo="0000164182"  ItemID="1452778282"/>
</HeaderCharge>   
<HeaderCharge ChargeCategory="ShippingDiscount" ChargeName="ShippingDiscount1" ChargeAmount="6.0" Reference="Discount">
    <Extn BaseChargeAmount="6.0" DeliveryCode="" DeliverySequenceNo="1" ConsignmentNo="0000164182"  ItemID="1452778282"
    POSDepartmentID="1097" PromotionID="100819" Description="" ReasonClass="PROMOVCH" ReasonCode="1230" ReasonDescription="50%off" />
</HeaderCharge>
<HeaderCharge ChargeCategory="ShippingDiscount" ChargeName="ShippingDiscount2" ChargeAmount="4.0" Reference="Discount 2">
    <Extn BaseChargeAmount="4.0" DeliveryCode="" DeliverySequenceNo="1" ConsignmentNo="0000164182"  ItemID="1452778282"
    POSDepartmentID="1097" PromotionID="100819" ReasonClass="PROMOVCH" ReasonCode="1230" ReasonDescription="50%off" />
</HeaderCharge>
<HeaderCharge ChargeCategory="ShippingCharge" ChargeName="ShippingCharge1" ChargeAmount="10.0" Reference="Free delivery">
    <Extn BaseChargeAmount="10.0" DeliveryCode="" DeliverySequenceNo="2" ConsignmentNo="0000164182"  ItemID="1452778282"/>
</HeaderCharge> 
    </HeaderCharges>
</Order>
```

Comment: can u show us ur code or output u want ?

Comment: added code for reference

Comment: can u add entire input xml ? the above input is only a part I guess

Comment: added sample input

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the functionality, but I could think of an alternative.instead of looping through all HeaderCharge elements loop only through them which satisfies your condition and again loop through them which doesnt satisfy. This way when you do a $$ you can get a separate sequence number for the objects with'ShippingCharge'

eg:

```
     ((h[?($.@ChargeCategory != "ShippingCharge")] default []) map ({
            //ur code here when not equals to shipping charges
        }

        ) when $.HeaderCharges != '' otherwise {}),
    ((h[?($.@ChargeCategory == "ShippingCharge")] default []) map ({
            //ur code here when equals to shipping charges
        }

        ) when $.HeaderCharges != '' otherwise {})
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  h[?($.@ChargeCategory != "ShippingCharge")] condition validation helps a lot for me

Comment: Hi tortoise, will the above condition work for the xml nodes? Im am trying check same on xml node instead of attribute, not working %input payload application/xml
%output application/java
---
using (c=payload.catalog.*category-assignment default [])

((c  default []) filter $.@mode != "delete" map ({
  
    ((c[?($.primary-flag == "true")] default []) map ({
            
            abc:"123"
        }))}))

Comment: sample xml -<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.mm.com/xml/impex/catalog/2006-10-31" catalog-id="HofCatalog">
<category-assignment product-id="D711069" category-id="DANIEL_4160"/>
<category-assignment product-id="D711069" primary-flag= "true" category-id="4160">
    <primary-flag>true</primary-flag>
  </category-assignment>
</catalog>